Characterisation of $\limsup$ of a function
Consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ open, $z^*\in\Omega$ and $f:\Omega\setminus\lbrace z^*\rbrace\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Then
$\limsup_{z\rightarrow z^*}|f(z)|:=\inf_{r>0}\sup_{z\in B_r (z^*)\cap\Omega}|f(z)|$ .
Now I wonder if the following characterisation, that would be useful to study the behavior of holomorphic functions near singularities, is true:
$R=\inf_{r>0}\sup_{z\in B_r (z^*)\cap\Omega\setminus\lbrace z^*\rbrace}|f(z)|\ \Rightarrow\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}|f(z_k)|=R\ \text{ for all sequences }z_k\rightarrow z^*$
For real functions $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ with $x^*=0$ and $x_k=\frac{1}{k\pi}$would be a counterexample. For then $\inf_{r>0}\sup_{z\in B_r (0)\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace}f(x)=1$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}f(x_k)=0$.
I wonder however if the implication holds for holomorphic functions. At least I found a solution to an exercise, that seems to use it (Exercise 4, Case 2).
I think you can proof the reverse statement "$\Leftarrow$" by considering the contraposition and constructing a sequence $z_k$, where $\sup_{k\geq n}|f(z_k)|$ is outside an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $R$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I just noticed that the implication is obviously wrong for essential singularities by Casorati-Weierstrass.
If $R<\infty$ however it is true: if $\limsup_{z\rightarrow z^*}|f(z)|<\infty$, f is locally bounded around $z^*$ and hence has a holomorphic (continous) extension by Riemann's theorem on removable singularities. So the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow z^*}|f(z_n)|$ exists and equals the $\limsup$.
